# Openpyxl: How to merge cells using variable rows

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I can't figure out how to merge cells without using the format 'A1:A4'

I want to be able to use ws.cell(row=x,column=y) format to set the start and end points of the merge.

The code below demonstrates what I want, but doesn't work as the range argument isn't in the correct format.

```py
for x in range(10):
    start = ws.cell(row=x,column=1)
    end = ws.cell(row=x, column=4)
    ws.merge_cells(start:end)
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

See the [manual](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html?highlight=merge_cells), we have the following:

> merge_cells(range_string=None, start_row=None, start_column=None, end_row=None, end_column=None)

so what you need to do is to do this instead:

```
for x in range(10):
    ws.merge_cells(start_row=x, start_column=1, end_row=x, end_column=4)
```