# How can I create a merged cell with a word in it in python

Tags: python, excel

I would like to create a merged cell in an excel document with a word in it:

The function would ideally take as an input arguments: start_row, start_col, finish_row, finish_col and word.

This function would edit the document such that I have a merged cell in the range given to the function.

An example usage:

[image]

In this example I would get a tralala word from column C to column E from row 1 to row 1.

Comment: See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56277796/openpyxl-how-to-merge-cells-using-variable-rows

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to handle excels is either by saving the excel sheet as CSV (which is an export option in excel) or by using pandas:

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

If you save the file as CSV and the built in function in pandas does not help you (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) you can do:

```
with open(filepathhere, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        line.split(";") # Find correct seperator here
        print(line) # Here you can find which index you want to retrieve to get your value.
```