# Truncate, copy and paste to another sheet - openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, loops, openpyxl, worksheet

Good day.

> "Import" sheet

[image: "Import" sheet]

> "Export" sheet

[image]

**The worksheet logic:** one source ip address can ping to different destination ips (e.g.[image] ).

**My task:** to iterate through the SRC_IP addresses (column=1), eliminate/truncate the duplicates. No need to write one source IP twice in "Export" sheet (for example, in "Import" sheet SRC_IP: 10.115.98.75 was written twice). The single copy of SRC_IP and SRC_RES from "Import" sheet should be copied to "Export" and the related DST_IP should be also copied to "Export" sheet but merged as shown above.

This is what I tried so far.

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment

file="C:/data2.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)

ws1=wb.worksheets[0]
ws2=wb.worksheets[1]


ls=[]

for i in ws1.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=1, values_only=True):
    ls.append(i)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: So you basically wanted the exported file to have automatic "merged cells" for duplicate SRC_IP and SRC_RES? If yes, study this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56277796/openpyxl-how-to-merge-cells-using-variable-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself.

```
import openpyxl
import math
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment, PatternFill
import collections
class Solution:
  def foo(self):
    file=str(input("File name: "))
    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
    sh1=str(input("Sheet 1: "))
    sh2=str((input("VLAN to work on: ")))
    if sh2 not in wb.sheetnames:
        wb.create_sheet(sh2)
    c=0 #counter
    
    ws1=wb[sh1]
    ws2=wb[sh2]
    
    map={0:0,1:1,2:5,3:6}
    d=collections.defaultdict(list)
    ls=dict()
    ws2.cell(row=1, column=1).value="SRC_IP"
    ws2.cell(row=1, column=2).value="SRC_Name"
    ws2.cell(row=1, column=3).value="DST_IP"
    ws2.cell(row=1, column=4).value="DST_Name"
    ws2.cell(row=1, column=5).value="PROTOCOL"
    ws2.cell(row=1, column=6).value="PORT"
    
    for rows in ws2.iter_rows(min_row=1, max_row=1, min_col=1, max_col=6):
        for cell in rows:
            cell.fill = PatternFill(start_color='00CCFFFF', end_color='00CCFFFF', fill_type="solid")
    
    for i,val in enumerate(ws1.iter_rows(min_row=2, min_col=1, values_only=True)):
        if sh2==val[2]:
            if val[5] is None:
                continue
            d[(val[0],val[1])].append((val[5],val[6] or "--Null--",val[11],val[10]))
            print(val)
        else:
            continue

    
    for (key,value) in d.items():
        if len(value)>=27:
            for i in range(c+2, c+2+math.ceil(len(value)/27)):
                ws2.row_dimensions[i].height=400
            ws2.merge_cells(start_row=c+2, end_row=c+1+math.ceil(len(value)/27), start_column=3, end_column=3) #0+1+2=3 2--3
            ws2.merge_cells(start_row=c+2, end_row=c+1+math.ceil(len(value)/27), start_column=4, end_column=4)
            ws2.merge_cells(start_row=c+2, end_row=c+1+math.ceil(len(value)/27), start_column=5, end_column=5)
            ws2.merge_cells(start_row=c+2, end_row=c+1+math.ceil(len(value)/27), start_column=6, end_column=6)
         
        ws2.cell(row=c+2, column=1).value=key[0] 
        #print(c+2,math.ceil(len(value)/27)+c+1)
        ws2.cell(row=c+2, column=2).value=key[1]
        ws2.cell(row=c+2, column=3).value="\n".join([item[0] for item in value])
        ws2.cell(row=c+2, column=4).value="\n".join([item[1] for item in value])
        ws2.cell(row=c+2, column=5).value="\n".join([item[2] for item in value])
        ws2.cell(row=c+2, column=6).value="\n".join([item[3] for item in value])
        
        c+=math.ceil(len(value)/27) #c=0 --> 0+2=2 --> c=2
        
        
    ws2.alignment=Alignment(wrap_text=True)
    wb.save(file)
    print("Done!")

    

 
p=Solution()
p.foo()
```